# Solr analytics around queries which yield zero hit count

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

Does Solr provide a way to access all queries which returned 0 hit count? I would like to get such statistics both in real time and in bulk, such as end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

The log output from Solr contains the rows and the time the query took; how you access those logs will depend on what application container you're using. You can use `tail` on the file to get real-time reports, or parse it at the end of the day to retrieve all queries that gave zero results.

An example from a live Tomcat installation:

> 169037029 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [xyz] webapp=/solr path=/select/ params={q=*:*&fl=*,score&start=0&fq=field:value&wt=phps} hits=1 status=0 QTime=1

`hits=1` is the amount of rows returned from Solr, while `QTime=1` is the milliseconds the actual query took to perform.